# Good solution for dynamic ABAC

Tags: data-structures, database-design, architecture, authorization, abac

I'm looking for some good solution where a user access to a resource is decided by multiple attributes that can change frequently.

for rules like

user X must have attribute X.a == (criteria) and attribute X.b == (another criteria)

to access resource R, where the a and b mentioned above changes frequently.

Each of the resources have this rules for them.

(like only users with X.a == (criteria) and X.b == (another criteria) can access this)

Q1) What will be a good data structure to represent this.

Q2) Implementation strategy For use cases like

- Listing all resources which a user can access. ( query ? )
- Checking eligibility before accessing resource r.X.

---

Elaborating the above with Example Scenario.

Consider An app where users can subscribe to courses.

- Completion of courses will gain them level (say level 1 to level 100).
  Being inactive will cause level to be dropped to previous one.
- The publisher of the course can specify course is available for users with level 3 Only. Or level 4 and above or even level 3 & 6 only etc..
- The users should not see the course anywhere even in the listing if they are not eligible according to the publisher's setting.

Currently I can think of making a many to many relationship from course to level ( considering levels are fixed ).
And when listing course for a user, I query courses by filtering course's associated levels and user's current level.

Also when there is multiple criteria like this, which depends on dynamic data.
Eg: user have different types of levels [programming level, marketing level, finance level]).

and each course have settings like

- User with programming level 5 and marking level 3 can access course a.
- User with finance level 4 or marketing level 3 can access course b.

and when a user with programming level 5 and marketing level 3 should see the list with course a and b.

a user with marketing level 3 should see the list with only course b.

Q1 & Q2) What would be optimal solution for this kind of implementation in terms of

Data structure

Querying all eligible entities

Checking eligibility for one entity

Comment: Could you give us a sample of an actual case? For instance, why given X.a = xyz and X.b = zyx yields X has access to R? Also, does 'x' means the same thing in both 'xyz' and 'zyx'?

Comment: Please see the example scenario, a user will gain levels ( which will change according to activity ) and he should have access to a resource based on the level he currently has. that's one but, I require to handle multiple attributes ( say user have different types of levels [programming level, marketing level, finance level]). and each course have settings like user with programming level 5 and marking level 3 can access this. or like finance level 4 or marketing level 3 can access this.